# How to generate the OpenID 1.1 sig based on assoc_handle?

Tags: java, openid, openid-provider

I have implemented an OpenID 1.1 provider in Java but I am having trouble with smart clients using an `assoc_handle` from `associate` coming up with different signatures. Dumb clients relying on `check_authentication` work fine. Specifically, I am testing against LiveJournal and it keeps returning:

> **signature_mismatch: Prior association invalidated ID provider response.**

The body of my `HMAC()` function is:

```
public static byte[] HMAC(byte[] secret, String token_contents) {
    SecretKey sk = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "HMACSHA1");
    Mac m = Mac.getInstance(sk.getAlgorithm());
    m.init(sk);
    return m.doFinal(token_contents.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

The `token_contents` for calling `HMAC()` comes from the following code during the handling for `checkid_setup`. That is, the signing is being done on `mode,identity,return_to` and this is also the value of the `signed` response parameter.

```
String token_contents = String.format(
    "mode:id_res\nidentity:%s\nreturn_to:%s\n",
    identity, return_to);
```

And finally, the `secret` is the base64-decoded version of `mac_key` returned by the initial `associate` call (e.g. retrieved via `secret(assoc_handle)` as per the spec). I've done a fair amount of testing to make sure the `enc_mac_key` can be decrypted properly.

*Any thoughts? Is there anything glaringly wrong with this?*

Or ... is there a simple, stand-alone client that anyone knows of which would do OpenID 1.1 and trace out its steps. Given that I may be able to figure out where I'm calculating things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was using [base64url encoding](https://brockallen.com/2014/10/17/base64url-encoding/) on output of key values (`mac_key`, `enc_mac_key`, `dh_server_public`) instead of standard base64. In [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) I was using `encodeBase64URLSafeString` instead of simply `encodeBase64String`. This was an unfortunate carry over from having worked in Open ID *Connect* previously and I misunderstood the nature of the function.

Anyway, something that helped me discover the answer was using the simply excellent [OpenID4Java](https://github.com/jbufu/openid4java) and its `simple-openid` JSP sample. Immediately it barfed out errors on my signature, complaining that it was 168 bits (instead of 160).